# Is there a way to see the shell commands executed by SmartGit?

Tags: git, smartgit

I am pretty new to git and am learning the general flow and all the command-line options.
However, sometimes I like to use the graphical interface of SmartGit in conjunction to the shell, especially if I am unsure of the best way to accomplish a flow task.

My question: Is there any way to see what git shell commands are executed by the tool.
I will probably eventually execute most git actions using the shell and only use the GUI for visuals.  Thus, it would be helpful to see how GUI actions translate into the actual git commands.

Comment: SourceTree has an option to display all the git commands it issues.  I prefer SourceTree to SmartGit.  http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since SmartGit 17, commands will always be shown.

For SmartGit 8.x (down to 5), make sure to have **Show executed command in Output view** selected in the Preferences, section **Commands**.

For SmartGit 4.6.x (and older), go to its settings directory (see About dialog), and uncomment following line in *smartgit.properties*:

```
smartgit.command.show=true
```

Comment: That's pretty much what I was looking for.  I like that it shows the git command in the Output pane of Smartgit.

Comment: Is there an updated version of this answer for SmartGit 18.x?

Answer (score 10):

In SmartGit 18 the git shell commands are shown in the "**Output Window**". You show/hide said window by clicking in the "Window" menu and selecting it, as it can be seen in this image.[image: this image]

I'm adding this remark because I closed the Output Window by mistake, and the main answer of this post turned out to be of no help.