# How does one see the git command line executed by the MacOSX Git GUI Tower?

Tags: macos, git, command-line, git-tower

Similar to "[Is there a way to see the shell commands executed by SmartGit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18832029/is-there-a-way-to-see-the-shell-commands-executed-by-smartgit)" is there a way to see the commands that the [Tower GUI](http://www.git-tower.com/) is executing on my behalf?  I want to learn the git command line at the same time I'm using the GUI.

Comment: Learn the command line by itself. The basic commands are not that difficult. 99% of what you normally do with git is covered by about six of them branch, checkout, add, commit, pull and push. Plenty of tutorials about. Output from the Gui is liable to be way more confusing.

Comment: At least for me, I learned git on a GUI, so there are things that the GUIs do very simply, and you can lookup references to, but the references use terms like upstream and FETCH_HEAD~{5}, which if you're used to GUIs may as well be another language. Its really helpful to be able to see what commands the GUI is using to do the things it does.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is possible if you enable Debug Logging in the Help menu. Then open Console.app and create a System Log Query like in the screenshot below. That will list all the commands that Tower.app executes for you. Note that it passes a lot of arguments that you normally wouldn't use yourself, so Tony's advice to learn the commands still applies.

[image: System Log Query]
[image: Example Tower log]

Comment: i cannot find a way to enable debug logging in the latest tower release.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to log the git commands by configuring my own git binary in Settings > Git config > Git binary
Its a simple shell script that runs the original git and logs the arguments to a log file (that you need to adjust)

```
#!/bin/bash

git "${@}"
echo "$(date +%s) git ${@}" >> /some/path/my.log
```